# Can I disable the Ubuntu splashscreen?

Tags: boot

I wanted to know if it is possible to disable the splashscreen at boot. The one where is says Ubuntu and it has the orange dots moving. I want to remove that and be able to see the commands like what you can see when it shuts down like stopping devices and stuff. Anyway this is is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Edit grub, paste this at a terminal: `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

Look for the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and change it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

save.

Then at terminal paste this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: # Wellcome :-) #

Comment: Thnx - saved 5s on boot.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on this exact problem all day...
Ubuntu Server 12.04.03 LTS amd64 on a [dual NIC, dual core Intel Atom](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007MS9OI2) with the N2000 graphics chipset. Had to blacklist the `gma500_gfx` driver to get video at all, and then on to seeing the boot up...

Editing the kernel parameters in <kbd>/etc/default/grub</kbd> to:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` 
did **not** work for me. The splash screen went away but the screen stayed blank.

Adding this to <kbd>/etc/default/grub</kbd> worked for me:
`GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text`