# change gui boot screen to text

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm trying to change the graphical boot screen, the one with the logo and 5 dots turning on and off to a text-only boot screen, preferably, high res( I guess it's called the boot sequence). I tried uncommenting `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in `/etc/default/grub` but it didn't work. I even added `set linux_gfx_mode=text` to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but that didn't work either. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Can I disable the Ubuntu splashscreen?](http://askubuntu.com/q/129738/52726) Follow the instructions in the accepted answer there.

Comment: My hands to God, I searched a lot! But didn't find that one, thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Ubuntu's [plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth#Toggling_to_Traditional_Text-based_Boot) wiki page, you need to remove splash from the kernel command line in grub.

Toggling to Traditional Text-based Boot

If you want to see the text-based boot messages (which use the Plymouth "details" plugin, press the ESCAPE key at any point when Plymouth is running. Note that the ESCAPE key acts as a toggle, so you can keep switching between graphical and text mode as required.

To have the boot start in "text mode" as early as possible, remove "splash" from the kernel command-line in grub.

To make the change permanent, update /etc/default/grub and run "sudo update-grub".

Updating the grub configuration manually is a potentially dangerous operation and can result in a machine that fails to boot without intervention. Do not attempt it unless you understand exactly what you are doing.

And try install the plymouth text theme from the ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Thanks. As a matter of fact I won't update it manually because understand I don't know what I'm doing exactly. I'll try to stick to safe methods.

Comment: I know I promised to play safe, but what the hell man :D. I changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` and then run sudo update-grub, and it turned out almost exactly the way I wanted it to. Thanks again