# Load Nvidia driver on boot

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, resolution

I Installed Nvidia manually, everything is ok, but Ubuntu starts and stop in low resolution ( during logo)

When I seached for answers I came across this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual
" **The X server will start in low-resolution if the nvidia driver is not loaded on boot, so
$ sudo gedit /etc/modules and add a line containing nvidia** "

Can anyone explain what should be added to module file that gets opened.

Answer (score 0):

I think it literally means to add "nvidia" to the end of the file.

$ `sudo su`
 # `echo "nvidia" >> /etc/modules`

or with gedit:

$ `gksu gedit /etc/modules`

I think you are just adding the module name to the file. That's why it's just nvidia.

Comment: Still the boot takes place in low resolution

Comment: Do you mean the splash screen? If so then that's normal behavior with the Nvidia driver. You can disable the splash if you want. It actually loads Ubuntu faster if you do. Here's AU link to do it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/129738/can-i-disable-the-ubuntu-splashscreen

Comment: No I want it to turn to my normal resolution, is that possible?

Comment: The splash screen is just something that gets shown *before* any drivers get loaded, so they default to VESA compliancy.  As some  NVidia cards support VGA only, that cannot be changed except by turning it off, so the above answer is the best you're going to get.  ;-)  (hint: accept!)