# modprobe of nvidia driver for GPU not loading at boot

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel

Problem is exactly as described in the title.

Here is my system details:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Card: GTX 980M

Driver: 3.43

My GPU computations with caffe don't work right on boot, it requires a `sudo modprobe nvidia-343-uvm`. I added `nvidia-343-uvm` to my `/etc/modules` file, but it still doesn't seem to want to boot when the system does like a normal module would. Any ideas?

Comment: have you had a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/456203/load-nvidia-driver-on-boot) yet?

Comment: Yes I did have a look there, and tried the solution before I posted this question; that's why I said that I added `nvidia-343-uvm` to my `/etc/modules` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you have hybrid Intel+NVIDIA graphics and also Nvidia 980M is not well supported by nvidia-343 driver. I do not know were did you get that driver from. As far as I know it was never included in Ubuntu repositories.

This can be fixed by

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo killall nvidia-persistenced
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: NVIDIA-SMI 460.27.04    Driver Version: 460.27.04    CUDA Version: 11.2: if I want to change from /etc/modprobe.d/ and write options nvidia NVreg_DeviceFileGID .... but not have result, how solve?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using this cmd line in grub?

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nocrs pci=realloc"
```

Comment: What is that and why can it solve the issue?

Comment: it makes the kernel to probe devices without looking to the firmware for hints.

Answer (score 1):

try running `nvidia-modprobe`

My server loaded the nvidia driver during boot on my headless server after doing this.

Comment: In most cases, this should be the answer. As the name implies, it wraps `modprobe`.

Comment: if I want to change from /etc/modprobe.d/ and write options nvidia NVreg_DeviceFileGID .... but not have result, may be try use options nvidia-modprobe NVreg_DeviceFileGID ?